# Escape color words on string

Tags: bash

I know how to color a string in bash script, and to count characters of a string. I do not know how to count a string with color tokens like `\033[0;32m` (Red) and `\033[0m` (Clear color). Examples are below:

```
>> echo "This is a string" | wc -c
17

>> echo -e "\033[0;32mThis is a string\033[0m" | wc -c
28

>> echo "\033[0;32mThis is a string\033[0m" | wc -c
34
```

ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: I've always had to eliminate the "color" information prior to processing the information, or tell the producing process "No color".

Comment: See: [Removing ANSI color codes from text stream](https://superuser.com/q/380772/340330)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to use `sed` to remove the extra characters, and count what is left.

```
#!/bin/bash
E=$'\e'   # An escape character, not everything understands \e but bash does
sed "s/${E}\\[[0-9;]*.//g" | wc -c
```

The pattern recognises lots of other sequences as well. If you are only interested in removing the colour ones, then change the `.` to `m`.

Personally I would not have the`| wc -c` in the script, being able to strip the colour sequences might be useful as a stand alone utility, as requested by @waltinator in the comments

Comment: Great! I thank you, sir.

Comment: You may improve your answer by this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450441/bash-should-not-count-color-codes-as-visible-characters

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto Improve it in what way? I am happy to improve the answer but I don't see anything in the link that helps.

Comment: Fair enough.  Could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: I tried on some other regular expressions, like Bold, Underline or Background, without success. I posted some tokens below, since It all that I know. I hope it may help us

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto So you had something like `echo -e '\033[4;30mBlack Underline\033[0m'` to get black underlined text, but when you fed it through the sed expression and then to wc -c you didn't get back 16, but instead got something line 27?

Comment: I had "Press \033[4;31many key\033[0m to continue..." and retrieved "Press \033any key\033 to continue..."

Comment: I found this post useful: https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto I don't understand what you are trying to say. Escape is 033 in octal. Did you omit the assignment to E ?